# Не работает PyQt интерфейс

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Я написал скрипт,который проверяет `IP` на спам базы. При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

```python
for server in blacklist:
    try:
        data = {'ip': per1, 'server': server}

        response = requests.post(per1, data=data, timeout=3)

        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise ValueError('Expected 200 OK')

        data = response.json()

        rating = data[data.keys()[0]]

        if rating != "":
            self.textEdit.setText(server + ": " + rating)
            core1()   
    except:
        self.textEdit.setText("NOT LISTED: " + server + "\n")
```

```python
import socket
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 80, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 120, 321, 291))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Push"))
    

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.list)

    def list(self):
        per1 = self.lineEdit.text()
                    
        url = 'http://www.ip-score.com/ajax_handler/get_bls'

        blacklist = [
            'access.redhawk.org', 'b.barracudacentral.org', 'bl.shlink.org', 'bl.spamcannibal.org',
            'bl.spamcop.net', 'bl.tiopan.com', 'blackholes.wirehub.net', 'blacklist.sci.kun.nl',
            'block.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'blocked.hilli.dk', 'bogons.cymru.com', 'cart00ney.surriel.com',
            'cbl.abuseat.org', 'cblless.anti-spam.org.cn', 'dev.null.dk', 'dialup.blacklist.jippg.org',
            'dialups.mail-abuse.org', 'dialups.visi.com', 'dnsbl.abuse.ch', 'dnsbl.anticaptcha.net',
            'dnsbl.antispam.or.id', 'dnsbl.dronebl.org', 'dnsbl.justspam.org', 'dnsbl.kempt.net',
            'dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dnsbl.tornevall.org', 'dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net', 'duinv.aupads.org',
            'dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net', 'dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net', 'dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dul.ru',
            'escalations.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'hil.habeas.com', 'black.junkemailfilter.com',
            'http.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'intruders.docs.uu.se', 'ips.backscatterer.org',
            'korea.services.net', 'l2.apews.org', 'mail-abuse.blacklist.jippg.org',
            'misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'msgid.bl.gweep.ca', 'new.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
            'no-more-funn.moensted.dk', 'old.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'opm.tornevall.org', 'pbl.spamhaus.org',
            'proxy.bl.gweep.ca', 'psbl.surriel.com', 'pss.spambusters.org.ar', 'rbl.schulte.org',
            'rbl.snark.net', 'recent.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'relays.bl.gweep.ca', 'relays.bl.kundenserver.de',
            'relays.mail-abuse.org', 'relays.nether.net', 'rsbl.aupads.org', 'sbl.spamhaus.org',
            'smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.olsentech.net',
            'spamguard.leadmon.net', 'spamsources.fabel.dk', 'tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de', 'ubl.unsubscore.com',
            'web.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'xbl.spamhaus.org', 'zen.spamhaus.org', 'zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
            'dnsbl.inps.de', 'dyn.shlink.org', 'rbl.megarbl.net', 'bl.mailspike.net']
                                    
                          
        for server in blacklist:
            try:
                data = {'ip': per1, 'server': server}
                                                                          
                response = requests.post(per1, data=data, timeout=3)
                                                                          
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    raise ValueError('Expected 200 OK')
                    
                data = response.json()
                                                                                
                rating = data[data.keys()[0]]
                                                
                if rating != "":
                    self.textEdit.setText(server + ": " + rating)
                    core1()   
            except:
                self.textEdit.setText("NOT LISTED: " + server + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, Вы нигде не создаёте объект `Window`. А значит, его конструктор не вызывается, и сигнал не связывается со слотом.

Comment: И кстати, когда копипастите откуда-то код, посмотрите, насколько читаемо он выглядит после вставки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да, @V-Mor вы правильно заметили, не создаётся объект класса `Window`, которое будет главным окном.

и еще вам надо добавить `Ui_MainWindow` как наследник для `class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):`

я не проверял вашу логику в методе `_list`. Если ваша проверка занимает много времени, вам будет необходим дополнительный поток.

```
import os
import socket
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 80, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 120, 321, 291))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Push"))
    
#                                   vvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                  # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._list)                  # _list !!!

    def _list(self):
        per1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        url = 'http://www.ip-score.com/ajax_handler/get_bls'
        blacklist = [
            'access.redhawk.org', 'b.barracudacentral.org', 'bl.shlink.org', 'bl.spamcannibal.org',
            'bl.spamcop.net', 'bl.tiopan.com', 'blackholes.wirehub.net', 'blacklist.sci.kun.nl',
            'block.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'blocked.hilli.dk', 'bogons.cymru.com', 'cart00ney.surriel.com',
            'cbl.abuseat.org', 'cblless.anti-spam.org.cn', 'dev.null.dk', 'dialup.blacklist.jippg.org',
            'dialups.mail-abuse.org', 'dialups.visi.com', 'dnsbl.abuse.ch', 'dnsbl.anticaptcha.net',
            'dnsbl.antispam.or.id', 'dnsbl.dronebl.org', 'dnsbl.justspam.org', 'dnsbl.kempt.net',
            'dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dnsbl.tornevall.org', 'dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net', 'duinv.aupads.org',
            'dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net', 'dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net', 'dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dul.ru',
            'escalations.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'hil.habeas.com', 'black.junkemailfilter.com',
            'http.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'intruders.docs.uu.se', 'ips.backscatterer.org',
            'korea.services.net', 'l2.apews.org', 'mail-abuse.blacklist.jippg.org',
            'misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'msgid.bl.gweep.ca', 'new.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
            'no-more-funn.moensted.dk', 'old.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'opm.tornevall.org', 'pbl.spamhaus.org',
            'proxy.bl.gweep.ca', 'psbl.surriel.com', 'pss.spambusters.org.ar', 'rbl.schulte.org',
            'rbl.snark.net', 'recent.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'relays.bl.gweep.ca', 'relays.bl.kundenserver.de',
            'relays.mail-abuse.org', 'relays.nether.net', 'rsbl.aupads.org', 'sbl.spamhaus.org',
            'smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.olsentech.net',
            'spamguard.leadmon.net', 'spamsources.fabel.dk', 'tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de', 'ubl.unsubscore.com',
            'web.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'xbl.spamhaus.org', 'zen.spamhaus.org', 'zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
            'dnsbl.inps.de', 'dyn.shlink.org', 'rbl.megarbl.net', 'bl.mailspike.net']
                          
        for server in blacklist:
            try:
                data = {'ip': per1, 'server': server}
                response = requests.post(per1, data=data, timeout=3)
                                                                          
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    raise ValueError('Expected 200 OK')

                data = response.json()
                rating = data[data.keys()[0]]
                                           
                if rating != "":
                    self.textEdit.setText(server + ": " + rating)
                    core1()   
            except:
#                self.textEdit.setText("NOT LISTED: " + server + "\n")
                self.textEdit.append("NOT LISTED: " + server)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    w = Window()                                                   # +
    w.show()                                                       # +
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

**Методы определения класса**

Вообще, вам стоило бы использовать какой-то один метод определения класса. По умолчанию обычно используется `def __init__(self):`, а класс главного окна должен сразу содержать конкретный объект `class MainWindow(QMainWindow):`

В вашем случае будет выглядеть так:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
         QMainWindow.__init__(self)
 
         self.resize(800, 600)
         self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
               ...
         # дальше остальной ваш код
```

Таком образом упрощается и вызов окна, вместо ваших четырех строк

```
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
```

Достаточно всего 2:

```
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.show()
```

---

**По поводу проблем открытия второго окна**

**1.** Я нигде не видел у вас в коде метода его вызова. Например, чего-то такого:

```
second_ui = Window()
second_ui.show())
```

Тем более, у вас не привязана кнопка к какой-либо функции. Должна быть такая строка:

`self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_second_ui)`, где `open_second_ui` - функция, внутри первого класса, запускающая второй класс при вызове.

**2.** Внутри второго класса вы попытались подключить кнопку `pushButton` к вызову функции `list()`, однако сама кнопка **во втором** классе не объявлена.

---

**Реализация открытия второго окна**

Я бы посоветовал совсем немного переделать код, чтобы в дальнейшем было удобнее работать.
Попробуйте использовать 3 класса, 2 из которых - окна, а третий - основной, показывающий нужное в конкретный момент окно. Идею реализации взял [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/439411).